# Android Sensors Timestamp reference

Tags: java, android, time, timestamp, android-sensors

Im working with Android sensors and introducing all kind of information in a DB. Ive been researching and I found out the timestamp reference that every device gives is different depending on the manufacturer (Somes use the "uptime" and others the seconds passed from 1970).

I need to use the time reference from 1970, so the only way it comes to my mind to do this issue is using the System function nanoTime() for every sensorEvent. Point is I need the application to be really fast (I do storage, visualization and other stuff) and I dont know if this would make the whole process slower...

What do you think guys?

Comment: What about `System.currentTimeMillis()`? Should be faster because it's less precise. Note that you're probably prematurely optimizing this. It's unlikely that the time function will be your bottleneck in this scenario. The bottleneck will probably be inserting into the DB.

Comment: But is still a System call...I dont know if is a good idea to use them really often (lets imagine a high rate device or the mobile phone using the fastest delay). 

Now I see your edit...thats would be the real question, if it would be a bottleneck or not...

Comment: I think you should try it. I've used System.currentTimeMillis() in performance critical applications without issues.

Comment: Yes I´ll try...anyway, I want to have the time in nanoseconds...do you think precision will be a real problem?

Comment: No I don't. If it would make you feel better, you could benchmark 1000 calls to `System.nanoTime()`, and see how it performs on average. My guess is it will be less than 1 millisecond per call. In fact I just created a test program, and 1,000,000 iterations of `nanoTime()` took 61 milliseconds. 100 iterations in less than a millisecond. That's pretty quick :)